# How to use SIMILAR TO with variables

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, plpgsql

I have a function with a `SELECT` using a `SIMILAR TO` expression with a variable and I don't know how to do it:

```
DECLARE pckg_data cl_data;
DECLARE contacts contacts_reg%ROWTYPE;
DECLARE sim_name varchar;
 BEGIN
SELECT client_reg._name, 
       client_reg.last_name, 
       client_reg.id_card, 
       client_reg.address
INTO pckg_data
FROM client_reg WHERE(client_reg._name = (cl_name ||' '|| cl_lastname));
RETURN NEXT pckg_data;

SELECT ('%'||cl_name || ' ' || cl_lastname ||'%') INTO sim_name;

FOR contacts IN SELECT contacts_reg.id 
FROM contacts_reg, contactscli_asc, client_reg
WHERE(contacts_reg._name SIMILAR TO sim_name) LOOP
    SELECT client_reg._name, client_reg.last_name, client_reg.id_card,
                   client_reg.address, client_reg.id
    INTO pckg_data
    FROM client_reg, contactscli_asc WHERE(contactscli_asc.contact = contacts.id 
    AND client_reg.id = contactscli_asc.client);
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: You haven't really made clear what the problem is. On the other hand, the `SELECT` driving your loop has no join conditions, so you're going to get the Cartesian product of all the tables -- which is usually not what people want. And you're selecting five values into one field.

Comment: @kgrittn - `pckg_data` may be a `record` variable

Comment: There is no point in posting only a fragment of a plpgsql function. Post a complete function definition (including the header) and add a description what it is meant to do, so we can make sense of it.

Comment: What do you get when you run just `SELECT contacts_reg.id FROM contacts_reg, contactscli_asc, client_reg WHERE(contacts_reg._name SIMILAR TO sim_name` (where `sim_name` is like `'%John Smith%'`)?

Comment: The function is *still* incomplete. The header is an integral part. And no explanation at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query that feeds the loop has `CROSS JOIN` over three (!) tables. I removed the last two on the notion that they are not needed. One of them is repeated in the body of the loop. Also consider @kgrittn's note on `CROSS JOIN`.

In the body of the loop you select data into a variable repeatedly, which *does nothing*. I assume you want to return those rows - that's what my edited version does, anyway.

I rewrote the `LOOP` construct with a simple `SELECT` with [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING), because that's much faster and simpler.

Actually, I **rewrote everything** in a way that would make sense. What you presented is still incomplete (missing function header) and syntactically and logically a mess.

This is an educated guess, no more:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION very_secret_function_name(cl_name varchar, cl_lastname varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (name varchar, last_name varchar,
                 id_card int, address varchar, id int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sim_name varchar := (cl_name ||' '|| cl_lastname);
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT c._name, c.last_name, c.id_card, c.address, NULL::int
           -- added NULL for an id to match the second call
   FROM   client_reg c
   WHERE  c._name = _sim_name;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT c._name, c.last_name, c.id_card, c.address, r.id
   FROM   client_reg      c
   JOIN   contactscli_asc a ON a.client = c.id
   JOIN   contacts_reg    r ON r.id = a.contact
   WHERE  r._name LIKE ('%' || _sim_name || '%');
END
$func$;
```

Else, consider the features used.

Some advise:

- You can assign a variable at declaration time.
- The keyword `DECLARE` is only needed once.
- Use table aliases to make your code easier to read.
- You don't have to enclose the `WHERE` clause in parenthesis.
- Most likely you don't need [`SIMILAR TO` and `LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) does the job faster. I never use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP). `LIKE` or regular expressions (`~`) do a better job:

  - [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: Thank you! I needed to know the "LIKE ('%' || _sim_name || '%')" syntax and couldn't find an example anywhere!